# Simple Adapter Null pointer

Tags: android, android-listview, nullpointerexception, simpleadapter

I am trying to store the data from an EditText into a ListView from another activity using a `SimpleAdapter` that is using pre defined rows from another XML file. All of this is defined in the button called `Save Todo` Everything works fine but when it comes to storing the data, I get a null pointer error. Image https://i.stack.imgur.com/DR5uA.png

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class Add_Item extends ActionBarActivity {
//variables
    EditText TaskNameET;
    Spinner SpinType;
    Button SaveTodo;
    String SpinnerOptions[] = {"OptionOne", "OptionTwo", "OptionThree"};
    SimpleAdapter ListAdapt;

//call mainactivity class
    MainActivity Main;

//declare arraylist and HashMap
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist;
    HashMap<String, String> map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add__item);

//define vars
        TaskNameET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TaskNameET);
        SpinType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        SaveTodo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

//initialize mylist and map 
        mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        map = new HashMap<String, String>();


//SimpleAdapter 
        ListAdapt = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.row, new String[] {"columnone", "columntwo", "columnthree"}, new int[] {R.id.columnone, R.id.columntwo, R.id.columnthree});

//adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> ard=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, SpinnerOptions);
        SpinType.setAdapter(ard);

//onclick todobutton
        SaveTodo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                map.put("columnone", Add_Item.this.TaskNameET.getText().toString());
                map.put("columntwo", Add_Item.this.TaskNameET.getText().toString());
                map.put("columnthree", Add_Item.this.TaskNameET.getText().toString());
                mylist.add(map);
               Main.MainList.setAdapter(ListAdapt);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add__item, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

//R.layout Add_Item XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.moduleonesimpleapplication.Add_Item" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="@string/TitleText"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/TaskNameET"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" >

        <requestFocus />

        <requestFocus />

    </EditText>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/TaskNameET"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TaskNameET"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TaskNameET"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/TaskNameTXT" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:text="@string/TaskDateTXT" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="date" >
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText2"
        android:text="@string/SaveButton" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
        android:text="@string/TaskTypeTxT" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

//R.layout Row.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/columnone"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#C0C0C0"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/columntwo"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#C0C0C0"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/columnthree"
            android:layout_width="120dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#C0C0C0"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: not sure what you expect `Main.MainList.setAdapter` to do, but I doubt this works.

Comment: it is suppose to add the stored data from the adapter into a listview on the MainActivity.java file

Comment: not going to work. inter-activity communication is slightly more complex than that.

Comment: can you post an example? this could be why I am getting a null pointer.

Comment: shuoldnt it be `MainActivity Main = new MainActivity();` ?

Comment: no, you cannot instanciate an activity your self. the system only can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize all variables (your map, your list etc.) in your `onCreate` method, not in the "declare" section.

I hope this helps ;)

EDIT:

According to your comment: setAdapter is being applied to a "null instance" of MainActivity. Why don't you create an static method in MainActivity which modifies your adapter? You will have to call it in the static way (`nameClass.nameMethod(..)`).

Be sure that this activity is always created after your MainActivity!

In your main activity:

- Make your `MainList` static
- Declare a static "mathod for having access to it:

  public static ListView getMainList(){return MainList;}

In your `Add_activity`:

- Delete your declaration `MainActivity main;`
- Change you line `MainActivty.Main.setAdap...` for

  MainActivity.getMainList().setAdapter(ListAdapt);

Eventhough... I think you are missing some points of Android basics because it's a really hard way of development for me.

Good luck!

Comment: thank yuo for your help, I declared the variables mylist and map into the declare section and moved the initialization into the oncreate method but I am still getting a null pointer, can you please recheck my code? I changed it.

Comment: I'll try. Just a minute ;)

Comment: Can you post your layout R.layout.activity_add__item?

Comment: I posted Row.xml also can you post an example of the static method in mainactivity? I don't fully understand what you mean

Comment: I edit my answer... I hope this would be a better option

Comment: there is a good chance that this will crash if, for instance, you switch application at some point and come back later.